# Print entire object in PyQGIS without being cut off with ellipsis

Tags: pyqgis, debugging

I am working in QGIS Python console (the editor to be more specific) and want to print an entire object using PyQGIS for debugging purposes. In my case it is a `QgsGeometry`, but I assume its the same for all.

Currently my print statement ends with an ellipsis `...`.

For example `print(myqgsgeometry)` returns:

```py
<QgsGeometry: MultiLineString ((685074.75568564038258046 5333734.68966723699122667, 689607.11533880967181176 5336606.67994251195341349, 691060.87634868768509477 5335754.98157308902591467, 694049.7252958765020594 5334003.93875554390251637),(694866.78128885303158313 5333546.30005178693681955, 696434.83353022579103708 5332976.09923674259334803, 697397.04740561358630657 5334223.41351965256035328, 698965.09964698634576052 5335149.98984409961849451, 698205.14828566065989435 5334700.92767604347318411, 701210.26535622449591756 5334686.70168187655508518, 703491.06861640303395689 5334829.25188563764095306),(704310.73228802974335849 5334936.16453845798969269, 705593.68412188009824604 5335720.19065914489328861, 705063.65025247924495488 5335396.28107228875160217, 705272.94616341753862798 5336682.4045345326885581, 704536.13231464137788862 5336937.4066283106803894, 705424.61259901942685246 5336227.4052277272567153, 703918.71922768652439117 5337430.79310427885502577, 702956.50535229872912169 5338321.731877786107361...>
```

All I can find on the internet is about Pandas, suggesting to use

```py
with option_context('display.max_rows', 10, 'display.max_columns', 5):
    print(stuff)
```

but of course this wont work for PyQGIS.

How can I **print** my entire `QgsGeometry` using PyQGIS?

Comment: `print(geom.asWkt())` is not trunctated. So maybe if it is possible to convert the objects to strings they are not truncated?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is a complex multipart polygon feature that looks like this:

[image: input]

And when I try to see the geometry either in QGIS or in CMD with:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("D:\\qgis_test\\divided.shp")

feat = next(vlayer.getFeatures())
print(feat.geometry())
```

it will truncate the coordinates:  `6156647.3...>`, as in your example.

There are several possible solutions to your problem:

1. the [`asJson()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ac86c01b71289527046eda8f1299aa520) method (also can be achieved via [`__geo_interface__`](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756)):

   ```py
   print(feat.geometry().asJson(precision=3))
   ```

   leads to:

   ```
   {"coordinates":[[[[6362955.219,6156700.664],[6362949.743,6156685.8],[6362948.458,6156686.56],[6362945.569,6156688.269],[6362941.033,6156690.952],[6362932.119,6156686.56],[6362926.569,6156683.825],[6362924.045,6156682.581],[6362914.117,6156677.689],[6362909.833,6156675.578],[6362907.023,6156673.892],[6362904.776,6156672.544],[6362896.833,6156667.778],[6362889.226,6156663.214],[6362886.966,6156661.858],[6362879.311,6156657.265],[6362878.995,6156656.751],[6362876.632,6156652.899],[6362873.229,6156647.351],[6362869.987,6156642.068],[6362869.976,6156642.05],[6362867.556,6156638.104],[6362864.653,6156633.373],[6362864.305,6156632.806],[6362861.234,6156627.8],[6362859.01,6156624.175],[6362858.649,6156623.588],[6362855.535,6156618.512],[6362852.624,6156613.766],[6362851.649,6156612.178],[6362848.969,6156607.809],[6362846.908,6156604.449],[6362846.295,6156603.451],[6362843.046,6156598.155],[6362840.27,6156593.63],[6362840.219,6156593.546],[6362833.867,6156583.193],[6362828.714,6156574.794],[6362827.901,6156573.468],[6362823.618,6156566.487],[6362822.825,6156565.194],[6362816.977,6156555.663],[6362815.452,6156553.177],[6362805.38,6156536.76],[6362803.236,6156553.177],[6362802.912,6156555.663],[6362801.667,6156565.194],[6362801.499,6156566.487],[6362800.587,6156573.468],[6362800.414,6156574.794],[6362799.317,6156583.193],[6362797.966,6156593.546],[6362797.955,6156593.63],[6362797.364,6156598.155],[6362796.672,6156603.451],[6362796.542,6156604.449],[6362796.103,6156607.809],[6362795.533,6156612.178],[6362795.432,6156612.952],[6362795.781,6156613.766],[6362797.815,6156618.512],[6362799.99,6156623.588],[6362800.242,6156624.175],[6362801.796,6156627.8],[6362803.941,6156632.806],[6362804.184,6156633.373],[6362808.067,6156642.434],[6362812.398,6156652.539],[6362816.512,6156662.139],[6362820.923,6156672.431],[6362822.563,6156676.257],[6362828.235,6156682.172],[6362836.521,6156690.813],[6362838.389,6156692.761],[6362846.076,6156695.248],[6362863.711,6156694.57],[6362865.789,6156690.813],[6362869.589,6156683.944],[6362868.681,6156682.172],[6362865.067,6156675.126],[6362862.924,6156672.431],[6362857.154,6156665.178],[6362853.004,6156662.139],[6362841.102,6156653.422],[6362841.04,6156652.539],[6362840.335,6156642.434],[6362839.745,6156633.978],[6362841.418,6156633.373],[6362842.985,6156632.806],[6362849.428,6156630.476],[6362850.371,6156630.135],[6362852.539,6156632.806],[6362852.999,6156633.373],[6362856.838,6156638.104],[6362860.039,6156642.05],[6362860.054,6156642.068],[6362860.093,6156642.117],[6362863.964,6156647.351],[6362868.067,6156652.899],[6362870.916,6156656.751],[6362874.693,6156661.858],[6362875.696,6156663.214],[6362876.146,6156663.822],[6362878.828,6156667.778],[6362882.059,6156672.544],[6362882.973,6156673.892],[6362885.189,6156677.161],[6362885.527,6156677.689],[6362888.656,6156682.581],[6362889.451,6156683.825],[6362891.2,6156686.56],[6362895.204,6156692.82],[6362897.624,6156696.604],[6362909.596,6156707.025],[6362909.833,6156707.231],[6362916.928,6156709.091],[6362929.458,6156712.375],[6362933.12,6156713.335],[6362941.338,6156709.057],[6362949.254,6156704.936],[6362949.624,6156704.744],[6362955.219,6156700.664]],[[6362963.93,6156677.408],[6362969.872,6156673.892],[6362972.152,6156672.544],[6362973.137,6156671.961],[6362973.688,6156667.778],[6362974.29,6156663.214],[6362974.468,6156661.858],[6362975.141,6156656.751],[6362975.649,6156652.899],[6362975.706,6156652.466],[6362976.38,6156647.351],[6362977.076,6156642.068],[6362977.078,6156642.05],[6362977.598,6156638.104],[6362978.221,6156633.373],[6362978.955,6156627.8],[6362979.433,6156624.175],[6362979.51,6156623.588],[6362980.179,6156618.512],[6362980.804,6156613.766],[6362981.014,6156612.178],[6362981.589,6156607.809],[6362982.032,6156604.449],[6362982.163,6156603.451],[6362982.861,6156598.155],[6362983.457,6156593.63],[6362983.468,6156593.546],[6362984.832,6156583.193],[6362985.016,6156581.797],[6362985.939,6156574.794],[6362986.113,6156573.468],[6362987.033,6156566.487],[6362987.203,6156565.194],[6362988.459,6156555.663],[6362991.903,6156529.525],[6362996.132,6156555.663],[6362997.674,6156565.194],[6362997.883,6156566.487],[6362999.013,6156573.468],[6362999.227,6156574.794],[6363000.36,6156581.797],[6363000.586,6156583.193],[6363002.262,6156593.546],[6363002.275,6156593.63],[6363003.007,6156598.155],[6363003.864,6156603.451],[6363004.026,6156604.449],[6363004.569,6156607.809],[6363005.276,6156612.178],[6363005.533,6156613.766],[6363005.694,6156614.761],[6363006.764,6156618.512],[6363008.212,6156623.588],[6363008.38,6156624.175],[6363009.414,6156627.8],[6363011.004,6156633.373],[6363012.353,6156638.104],[6363013.479,6156642.05],[6363013.484,6156642.068],[6363014.991,6156647.351],[6363016.45,6156652.466],[6363016.574,6156652.899],[6363017.672,6156656.751],[6363019.13,6156661.858],[6363019.516,6156663.214],[6363020.818,6156667.778],[6363022.178,6156672.544],[6363022.562,6156673.892],[6363023.646,6156677.689],[6363025.041,6156682.581],[6363025.396,6156683.825],[6363026.176,6156686.56],[6363026.268,6156686.883],[6363028.53,6156692.82],[6363030.487,6156697.956],[6363032.211,6156702.483],[6363033.653,6156706.269],[6363035.96,6156712.323],[6363037.024,6156715.116],[6363037.12,6156715.37],[6363043.172,6156722.236],[6363044.893,6156724.189],[6363051.202,6156731.347],[6363053.375,6156733.813],[6363060.634,6156742.048],[6363062.199,6156742.576],[6363070.19,6156745.268],[6363081.434,6156749.057],[6363092.747,6156747.25],[6363109.024,6156744.65],[6363113.99,6156743.857],[6363114.962,6156742.576],[6363115.255,6156742.189],[6363121.61,6156733.813],[6363123.481,6156731.347],[6363123.938,6156730.744],[6363123.36,6156724.189],[6363123.188,6156722.236],[6363122.559,6156715.116],[6363122.313,6156712.323],[6363121.903,6156707.683],[6363121.54,6156706.269],[6363120.568,6156702.483],[6363119.405,6156697.956],[6363118.086,6156692.82],[6363116.477,6156686.56],[6363115.775,6156683.825],[6363115.573,6156683.039],[6363114.937,6156683.825],[6363107.886,6156692.535],[6363107.642,6156693.233],[6363104.534,6156702.134],[6363100.411,6156713.94],[6363097.938,6156721.022],[6363087.696,6156724.694],[6363085.955,6156725.318],[6363076.686,6156720.118],[6363076.848,6156713.94],[6363077.138,6156702.935],[6363078.125,6156702.134],[6363089.097,6156693.233],[6363089.121,6156693.213],[6363090.595,6156683.825],[6363090.79,6156682.581],[6363091.558,6156677.689],[6363092.155,6156673.892],[6363092.366,6156672.544],[6363093.115,6156667.778],[6363093.416,6156665.856],[6363092.764,6156663.214],[6363092.429,6156661.858],[6363091.167,6156656.751],[6363090.215,6156652.899],[6363090.108,6156652.466],[6363088.845,6156647.351],[6363088.669,6156646.639],[6363083.84,6156642.068],[6363083.821,6156642.05],[6363079.652,6156638.104],[6363074.654,6156633.373],[6363074.055,6156632.806],[6363068.766,6156627.8],[6363064.936,6156624.175],[6363064.316,6156623.588],[6363059.051,6156618.604],[6363058.966,6156618.512],[6363054.621,6156613.766],[6363053.167,6156612.178],[6363049.166,6156607.809],[6363046.09,6156604.449],[6363045.176,6156603.451],[6363041.868,6156599.839],[6363042.138,6156598.155],[6363042.862,6156593.63],[6363042.875,6156593.546],[6363043.677,6156588.534],[6363053.264,6156588.403],[6363063.48,6156588.263],[6363073.546,6156588.125],[6363076.686,6156588.082],[6363084.076,6156593.546],[6363084.189,6156593.63],[6363090.309,6156598.155],[6363097.472,6156603.451],[6363098.821,6156604.449],[6363103.366,6156607.809],[6363109.274,6156612.178],[6363111.422,6156613.766],[6363113.99,6156615.665],[6363115.453,6156618.512],[6363118.06,6156623.588],[6363118.361,6156624.175],[6363120.223,6156627.8],[6363122.795,6156632.806],[6363123.086,6156633.373],[6363125.516,6156638.104],[6363127.542,6156642.05],[6363127.552,6156642.068],[6363130.265,6156647.351],[6363132.892,6156652.466],[6363133.115,6156652.899],[6363135.093,6156656.751],[6363137.716,6156661.858],[6363138.413,6156663.214],[6363140.757,6156667.778],[6363143.205,6156672.544],[6363143.834,6156673.77],[6363143.837,6156673.892],[6363143.94,6156677.689],[6363144.071,6156682.581],[6363144.105,6156683.825],[6363144.178,6156686.56],[6363144.347,6156692.82],[6363144.485,6156697.956],[6363144.607,6156702.483],[6363144.708,6156706.269],[6363144.871,6156712.323],[6363144.946,6156715.116],[6363145.138,6156722.236],[6363145.191,6156724.187],[6363145.19,6156724.189],[6363143.73,6156731.347],[6363143.228,6156733.813],[6363141.519,6156742.189],[6363141.44,6156742.576],[6363139.497,6156752.105],[6363138.182,6156758.553],[6363136.319,6156761.657],[6363130.117,6156771.994],[6363125.973,6156778.901],[6363107.652,6156778.515],[6363091.873,6156778.183],[6363075.196,6156777.832],[6363061.538,6156777.544],[6363053.447,6156771.994],[6363038.377,6156761.657],[6363034.181,6156758.779],[6363029.97,6156752.105],[6363023.958,6156742.576],[6363022.199,6156739.787],[6363018.506,6156733.813],[6363016.982,6156731.347],[6363012.559,6156724.189],[6363011.352,6156722.236],[6363009.764,6156719.665],[6363007.628,6156715.116],[6363006.317,6156712.323],[6363004.564,6156708.587],[6363002.864,6156706.269],[6363000.088,6156702.483],[6362999.59,6156701.805],[6362999.192,6156701.638],[6362990.387,6156697.956],[6362987.155,6156696.604],[6362974.208,6156692.82],[6362972.459,6156692.309],[6362971.104,6156692.82],[6362969.672,6156693.36],[6362963.93,6156677.408]]]],"type":"MultiPolygon"}
   ```
2. as was mentioned by @BERA the [`asWkt()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ac86c01b71289527046eda8f1299aa520) method:

   ```py
   print(feat.geometry().asWkt(precision=3))
   ```

   leads to:

   ```
   MultiPolygon (((6362955.219 6156700.664, 6362949.743 6156685.8, 6362948.458 6156686.56, 6362945.569 6156688.269, 6362941.033 6156690.952, 6362932.119 6156686.56, 6362926.569 6156683.825, 6362924.045 6156682.581, 6362914.117 6156677.689, 6362909.833 6156675.578, 6362907.023 6156673.892, 6362904.776 6156672.544, 6362896.833 6156667.778, 6362889.226 6156663.214, 6362886.966 6156661.858, 6362879.311 6156657.265, 6362878.995 6156656.751, 6362876.632 6156652.899, 6362873.229 6156647.351, 6362869.987 6156642.068, 6362869.976 6156642.05, 6362867.556 6156638.104, 6362864.653 6156633.373, 6362864.305 6156632.806, 6362861.234 6156627.8, 6362859.01 6156624.175, 6362858.649 6156623.588, 6362855.535 6156618.512, 6362852.624 6156613.766, 6362851.649 6156612.178, 6362848.969 6156607.809, 6362846.908 6156604.449, 6362846.295 6156603.451, 6362843.046 6156598.155, 6362840.27 6156593.63, 6362840.219 6156593.546, 6362833.867 6156583.193, 6362828.714 6156574.794, 6362827.901 6156573.468, 6362823.618 6156566.487, 6362822.825 6156565.194, 6362816.977 6156555.663, 6362815.452 6156553.177, 6362805.38 6156536.76, 6362803.236 6156553.177, 6362802.912 6156555.663, 6362801.667 6156565.194, 6362801.499 6156566.487, 6362800.587 6156573.468, 6362800.414 6156574.794, 6362799.317 6156583.193, 6362797.966 6156593.546, 6362797.955 6156593.63, 6362797.364 6156598.155, 6362796.672 6156603.451, 6362796.542 6156604.449, 6362796.103 6156607.809, 6362795.533 6156612.178, 6362795.432 6156612.952, 6362795.781 6156613.766, 6362797.815 6156618.512, 6362799.99 6156623.588, 6362800.242 6156624.175, 6362801.796 6156627.8, 6362803.941 6156632.806, 6362804.184 6156633.373, 6362808.067 6156642.434, 6362812.398 6156652.539, 6362816.512 6156662.139, 6362820.923 6156672.431, 6362822.563 6156676.257, 6362828.235 6156682.172, 6362836.521 6156690.813, 6362838.389 6156692.761, 6362846.076 6156695.248, 6362863.711 6156694.57, 6362865.789 6156690.813, 6362869.589 6156683.944, 6362868.681 6156682.172, 6362865.067 6156675.126, 6362862.924 6156672.431, 6362857.154 6156665.178, 6362853.004 6156662.139, 6362841.102 6156653.422, 6362841.04 6156652.539, 6362840.335 6156642.434, 6362839.745 6156633.978, 6362841.418 6156633.373, 6362842.985 6156632.806, 6362849.428 6156630.476, 6362850.371 6156630.135, 6362852.539 6156632.806, 6362852.999 6156633.373, 6362856.838 6156638.104, 6362860.039 6156642.05, 6362860.054 6156642.068, 6362860.093 6156642.117, 6362863.964 6156647.351, 6362868.067 6156652.899, 6362870.916 6156656.751, 6362874.693 6156661.858, 6362875.696 6156663.214, 6362876.146 6156663.822, 6362878.828 6156667.778, 6362882.059 6156672.544, 6362882.973 6156673.892, 6362885.189 6156677.161, 6362885.527 6156677.689, 6362888.656 6156682.581, 6362889.451 6156683.825, 6362891.2 6156686.56, 6362895.204 6156692.82, 6362897.624 6156696.604, 6362909.596 6156707.025, 6362909.833 6156707.231, 6362916.928 6156709.091, 6362929.458 6156712.375, 6362933.12 6156713.335, 6362941.338 6156709.057, 6362949.254 6156704.936, 6362949.624 6156704.744, 6362955.219 6156700.664),(6362963.93 6156677.408, 6362969.872 6156673.892, 6362972.152 6156672.544, 6362973.137 6156671.961, 6362973.688 6156667.778, 6362974.29 6156663.214, 6362974.468 6156661.858, 6362975.141 6156656.751, 6362975.649 6156652.899, 6362975.706 6156652.466, 6362976.38 6156647.351, 6362977.076 6156642.068, 6362977.078 6156642.05, 6362977.598 6156638.104, 6362978.221 6156633.373, 6362978.955 6156627.8, 6362979.433 6156624.175, 6362979.51 6156623.588, 6362980.179 6156618.512, 6362980.804 6156613.766, 6362981.014 6156612.178, 6362981.589 6156607.809, 6362982.032 6156604.449, 6362982.163 6156603.451, 6362982.861 6156598.155, 6362983.457 6156593.63, 6362983.468 6156593.546, 6362984.832 6156583.193, 6362985.016 6156581.797, 6362985.939 6156574.794, 6362986.113 6156573.468, 6362987.033 6156566.487, 6362987.203 6156565.194, 6362988.459 6156555.663, 6362991.903 6156529.525, 6362996.132 6156555.663, 6362997.674 6156565.194, 6362997.883 6156566.487, 6362999.013 6156573.468, 6362999.227 6156574.794, 6363000.36 6156581.797, 6363000.586 6156583.193, 6363002.262 6156593.546, 6363002.275 6156593.63, 6363003.007 6156598.155, 6363003.864 6156603.451, 6363004.026 6156604.449, 6363004.569 6156607.809, 6363005.276 6156612.178, 6363005.533 6156613.766, 6363005.694 6156614.761, 6363006.764 6156618.512, 6363008.212 6156623.588, 6363008.38 6156624.175, 6363009.414 6156627.8, 6363011.004 6156633.373, 6363012.353 6156638.104, 6363013.479 6156642.05, 6363013.484 6156642.068, 6363014.991 6156647.351, 6363016.45 6156652.466, 6363016.574 6156652.899, 6363017.672 6156656.751, 6363019.13 6156661.858, 6363019.516 6156663.214, 6363020.818 6156667.778, 6363022.178 6156672.544, 6363022.562 6156673.892, 6363023.646 6156677.689, 6363025.041 6156682.581, 6363025.396 6156683.825, 6363026.176 6156686.56, 6363026.268 6156686.883, 6363028.53 6156692.82, 6363030.487 6156697.956, 6363032.211 6156702.483, 6363033.653 6156706.269, 6363035.96 6156712.323, 6363037.024 6156715.116, 6363037.12 6156715.37, 6363043.172 6156722.236, 6363044.893 6156724.189, 6363051.202 6156731.347, 6363053.375 6156733.813, 6363060.634 6156742.048, 6363062.199 6156742.576, 6363070.19 6156745.268, 6363081.434 6156749.057, 6363092.747 6156747.25, 6363109.024 6156744.65, 6363113.99 6156743.857, 6363114.962 6156742.576, 6363115.255 6156742.189, 6363121.61 6156733.813, 6363123.481 6156731.347, 6363123.938 6156730.744, 6363123.36 6156724.189, 6363123.188 6156722.236, 6363122.559 6156715.116, 6363122.313 6156712.323, 6363121.903 6156707.683, 6363121.54 6156706.269, 6363120.568 6156702.483, 6363119.405 6156697.956, 6363118.086 6156692.82, 6363116.477 6156686.56, 6363115.775 6156683.825, 6363115.573 6156683.039, 6363114.937 6156683.825, 6363107.886 6156692.535, 6363107.642 6156693.233, 6363104.534 6156702.134, 6363100.411 6156713.94, 6363097.938 6156721.022, 6363087.696 6156724.694, 6363085.955 6156725.318, 6363076.686 6156720.118, 6363076.848 6156713.94, 6363077.138 6156702.935, 6363078.125 6156702.134, 6363089.097 6156693.233, 6363089.121 6156693.213, 6363090.595 6156683.825, 6363090.79 6156682.581, 6363091.558 6156677.689, 6363092.155 6156673.892, 6363092.366 6156672.544, 6363093.115 6156667.778, 6363093.416 6156665.856, 6363092.764 6156663.214, 6363092.429 6156661.858, 6363091.167 6156656.751, 6363090.215 6156652.899, 6363090.108 6156652.466, 6363088.845 6156647.351, 6363088.669 6156646.639, 6363083.84 6156642.068, 6363083.821 6156642.05, 6363079.652 6156638.104, 6363074.654 6156633.373, 6363074.055 6156632.806, 6363068.766 6156627.8, 6363064.936 6156624.175, 6363064.316 6156623.588, 6363059.051 6156618.604, 6363058.966 6156618.512, 6363054.621 6156613.766, 6363053.167 6156612.178, 6363049.166 6156607.809, 6363046.09 6156604.449, 6363045.176 6156603.451, 6363041.868 6156599.839, 6363042.138 6156598.155, 6363042.862 6156593.63, 6363042.875 6156593.546, 6363043.677 6156588.534, 6363053.264 6156588.403, 6363063.48 6156588.263, 6363073.546 6156588.125, 6363076.686 6156588.082, 6363084.076 6156593.546, 6363084.189 6156593.63, 6363090.309 6156598.155, 6363097.472 6156603.451, 6363098.821 6156604.449, 6363103.366 6156607.809, 6363109.274 6156612.178, 6363111.422 6156613.766, 6363113.99 6156615.665, 6363115.453 6156618.512, 6363118.06 6156623.588, 6363118.361 6156624.175, 6363120.223 6156627.8, 6363122.795 6156632.806, 6363123.086 6156633.373, 6363125.516 6156638.104, 6363127.542 6156642.05, 6363127.552 6156642.068, 6363130.265 6156647.351, 6363132.892 6156652.466, 6363133.115 6156652.899, 6363135.093 6156656.751, 6363137.716 6156661.858, 6363138.413 6156663.214, 6363140.757 6156667.778, 6363143.205 6156672.544, 6363143.834 6156673.77, 6363143.837 6156673.892, 6363143.94 6156677.689, 6363144.071 6156682.581, 6363144.105 6156683.825, 6363144.178 6156686.56, 6363144.347 6156692.82, 6363144.485 6156697.956, 6363144.607 6156702.483, 6363144.708 6156706.269, 6363144.871 6156712.323, 6363144.946 6156715.116, 6363145.138 6156722.236, 6363145.191 6156724.187, 6363145.19 6156724.189, 6363143.73 6156731.347, 6363143.228 6156733.813, 6363141.519 6156742.189, 6363141.44 6156742.576, 6363139.497 6156752.105, 6363138.182 6156758.553, 6363136.319 6156761.657, 6363130.117 6156771.994, 6363125.973 6156778.901, 6363107.652 6156778.515, 6363091.873 6156778.183, 6363075.196 6156777.832, 6363061.538 6156777.544, 6363053.447 6156771.994, 6363038.377 6156761.657, 6363034.181 6156758.779, 6363029.97 6156752.105, 6363023.958 6156742.576, 6363022.199 6156739.787, 6363018.506 6156733.813, 6363016.982 6156731.347, 6363012.559 6156724.189, 6363011.352 6156722.236, 6363009.764 6156719.665, 6363007.628 6156715.116, 6363006.317 6156712.323, 6363004.564 6156708.587, 6363002.864 6156706.269, 6363000.088 6156702.483, 6362999.59 6156701.805, 6362999.192 6156701.638, 6362990.387 6156697.956, 6362987.155 6156696.604, 6362974.208 6156692.82, 6362972.459 6156692.309, 6362971.104 6156692.82, 6362969.672 6156693.36, 6362963.93 6156677.408)))
   ```

Comment: This is true for geometry, especially converting to strings using the .asWkt() method; still I was hoping for a general solution for PyQGIS objects.